# QGIS 2.0 OpenLayers Google Maps/Satellite do not work

Tags: qgis-2

I have been using QGIS version 2.0 with Google Satellite layers for a few months. The last time I used was in mid Oct 2014. In mid Nov 2014, Google Satellite or Google Map suddenly does not work any longer. I'm unable to zoom in or zoom to the layer extent. It is showing a static graphic of Google map in a high scale. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the OpenLayers plugin, but it still didn't work. I tried to change the CRS Layers from EPSG:3857 to many different layers. It still does not work.  Can someone please help?

Below is snapshot of what happened to the Google Satellite or Map.

[image: Pictures of QGIS Problem]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, first load a shapefile of your own, set **Project** CRS to EPSG:3857, then load Google satellite and zoom to the **shapefile layer** extent.

By the way, QGIS 2.0 is outdated, the current version is 2.6.1, and the current version of the Openlayers plugin will not work with QGIS 2.0 anymore. So I suggest to update to the current version of both.

Comment: Thank you Andre!  I tried the suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I will ask the IT team to upgrade the QGIS to version 2.6 then. Hopefully, it will resolve the problem.